# Indicar um plugin ou o possível caminho da resposta?

Tags: debate

Vi um caso hoje e queria saber qual a melhor maneira de responder uma dúvida. A pessoa queria um efeito X, e a resposta rápida/simples era "use o plugin X.js" que tem tudo pronto ou indicar um caminho (que seria mais longo) para que a pessoa possa chegar ao resultado, do tipo, "tente fazer tal coisa, tente usar tal método, da seguinte maneira".

Answer (score 6):

Para oferecer dicas rápidas, use os comentários:

- você está ajudando a pessoa;
- apesar de ser uma "resposta", um comentário não vai receber votos negativos nem corre o risco (grande) de ser deletado pela comunidade.

Respostas que contém apenas um link são consideradas de baixa qualidade, passíveis de serem sinalizadas como tal:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Uma vez sinalizadas, essas respostas vão parar na fila de análise de Publicações de Baixa Qualidade. Tem vezes que o próprio sistema, baseado no comprimento do post, coloca essas respostas na fila de análise.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

O comentário "Embora este link possa responder à pergunta..." é um dos *templates* que o sistema oferece na hora de votar pela exclusão de um post de baixa qualidade.

---

Resumindo: se quer dar uma ajuda rápida, faça um comentário com o link. Se quer explicar melhor e usar o link como material extra, escreva uma resposta completa seguindo as orientações do guia [Como Responder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

---

<sub>PS: Acabo de me dar conta que o exemplo que mostrei acima da fila de análise é uma exceção, já que a [própria pergunta está pedindo por um link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37377/existe-uma-vers%C3%A3o-do-matplotlib-para-o-python-3-4-para-o-mac). Nesses casos, a probabilidade é grande de que a pergunta seja descontextualizada (off-topic), e é a pergunta que tem que ser negativada e/ou votada para fechamento/remoção. Para cúmulo da exceção, não tenho certeza de como essa pergunta/resposta deve ser manejada...</sub>

Comment: Também estou em dúvida sobre como tratar essa pergunta+resposta. Por ora, restaurei a resposta, que tinha sido deletada pela fila de análise.

Comment: @brasofilo foi um bom exemplo eheheh